# Reading pictures from the storage

Tags: android

I am practicing working with android programming and ran into this problem. In the view pager I have a fragment that holds a grid view loading images from ***ArrayList images***. When I click on the thumbnail it will go to an activity show the full size image called ***FullScreenActivity***.The problem is some images can load to ***FullScreenActivity*** but some cannot just like the attached picture. I have checked the uri and think that everything should be normal. What did I do wrong? Thank for helping me.

Here is the logcat I received when clicked on the picture that fail to show me on full screen (sorry if it is too long!).

```
    2020-02-08 22:57:21.822 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:700560615
2020-02-08 22:57:21.837 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2020-02-08 22:57:21.841 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.lovereminder, PackageName:com.example.lovereminder
2020-02-08 22:57:21.877 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x72237c9000)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.879 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x72237c9000,api=1)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.880 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-02-08 22:57:21.880 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder I/libEGL: [MTK Game SDK] low_latency_mode(0) pid(-1) property(-1)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.882 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@cedb46f
2020-02-08 22:57:21.901 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: [0]: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29815
2020-02-08 22:57:21.901 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: [1]: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29755
2020-02-08 22:57:21.901 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: [2]: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29766
2020-02-08 22:57:21.901 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: [3]: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29754
2020-02-08 22:57:21.901 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: [4]: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29753
2020-02-08 22:57:21.901 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: [5]: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29772
2020-02-08 22:57:21.904 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@cd093fe[]
2020-02-08 22:57:21.906 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/ViewRootImpl[FullScreenPicActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2020-02-08 22:57:21.909 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@6315275, this = DecorView@cd093fe[FullScreenPicActivity]
2020-02-08 22:57:21.920 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: 3
2020-02-08 22:57:21.921 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder I/chatty: uid=10240(com.example.lovereminder) identical 1 line
2020-02-08 22:57:21.922 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/TAG: 3
2020-02-08 22:57:21.932 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x72232f2000)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.932 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x72232f2000,api=1)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.934 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-02-08 22:57:21.934 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder I/libEGL: [MTK Game SDK] low_latency_mode(0) pid(-1) property(-1)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.942 9046-9277/com.example.lovereminder I/ActivityThread: com.android.providers.media.documents acquiringCount 3
2020-02-08 22:57:21.945 9046-9278/com.example.lovereminder I/ActivityThread: com.android.providers.media.documents acquiringCount 4
2020-02-08 22:57:21.945 9046-9277/com.example.lovereminder E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6112)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2617)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1841)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1455)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1308)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1028)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:50)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:12749)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:13179)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:358)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3408)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.947 9046-9278/com.example.lovereminder E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6112)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2617)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1841)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1455)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1308)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1028)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:50)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.971 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder W/Glide: Load failed for content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29754 with size [1080x2110]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.lang.SecurityException(Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
2020-02-08 22:57:21.971 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6112)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2617)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1841)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1455)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1308)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1028)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:50)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:12749)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:13179)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:358)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3408)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
2020-02-08 22:57:21.971 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder W/Glide: Load failed for content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29766 with size [1080x2110]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.lang.SecurityException(Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
2020-02-08 22:57:21.972 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{77e4e4d 9046:com.example.lovereminder/u0a240} (pid=9046, uid=10240) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6112)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2617)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1841)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1455)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1308)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1028)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:50)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
2020-02-08 22:57:22.494 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7223782000,api=1)
2020-02-08 22:57:22.516 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Tag: Pic Frag Stopped
2020-02-08 22:57:22.516 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Tag: Dia Frag Stopped
2020-02-08 22:57:22.520 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@16a38a8, this = DecorView@24de445[MainActivity]
2020-02-08 22:57:22.521 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Tag: Pic Frag Destroyed View
2020-02-08 22:57:22.525 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Tag: Pic Frag Destroyed
2020-02-08 22:57:22.525 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Tag: Dia Frag Destroyed View
2020-02-08 22:57:22.527 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/Tag: Dia Frag Destroyed
2020-02-08 22:57:22.548 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@24de445[MainActivity]
2020-02-08 22:57:25.326 9046-9150/com.example.lovereminder D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x72237c9000,api=1)
2020-02-08 22:57:25.329 9046-9046/com.example.lovereminder D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{808047 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-880,440}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any exception? How you are loading images? Are the images on your phone or you loading them from url? Probably you are not using any library for image loading and catching...

Comment: No, there is no exception, the app still running. And for the library loading images, I used Glide to load the Uri from the ArrayList

Comment: Glide is definitely best. So there is probably no problem outofmemory issues. But can't give any solution unless you give some more input. Try to post logcat here. Will check. Also try picasso once instead of glide. See the problem is still there with picasso.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the logcat. As I am new to ask on SO, if I didnt make sth right, please tell

Comment: All right are there any images you loading from local storage? I see multiple ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT issues. This problem occurs with uri you get from local storage. So either your local storage uri are not accessed using the above flag or there is permission related issue happening with glide.

Comment: yes I do, I chose the images from gallery and add them to Shared Preferences to store the Uri's list. But how can I fix this? Why there are pictures that I can click and see (p.s: I can only see the first 2 pics, the rest isn't shown up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem you are having is not about loading the images but aquiring them.

I faced similar situation recently but my needs weren't specific to images. So I will give you my solution and you can modify the way you want.

```
fun choosePicker(filePicker: FilePickerOption) { // FilePickerOption is just a enum class
    when (filePicker) {
        FilePickerOption.CAMERA -> {
            Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                    override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                        val values = ContentValues()
                        cameraImageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)!!

                        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraImageUri)
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, customRequestCodeCamera)
                    }

                    override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                        permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?, token: PermissionToken?) {

                    }
                }).check()
        }
        FilePickerOption.GALLERY -> {
            Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                    override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                        val toChoose = Intent().setType("image/*").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true).setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(toChoose, "CHOOSE IMAGES"), customRequestCodeGallery)
                    }

                    override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                        permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?, token: PermissionToken?) {

                    }
                }).check()
        }
        FilePickerOption.FILE -> {

                Dexter.withActivity(this)
                    .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                        override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                            val toChoose = Intent().setType("*/*").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true).setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(toChoose, "CHOOSE FILES"), customRequestCodeFile)
                        }

                        override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                            permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?, token: PermissionToken?) {

                        }
                    }).check()
        }
    }
}
```

After Picker is open you can get result following way

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    when (requestCode) {
        customRequestCodeCamera -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (::cameraImageUri.isInitialized) {
                val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(cameraImageUri)
                val file = File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/MyApp/${Utils.getNameFromUri(contentResolver, cameraImageUri)?:""}")
                file.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream!!)
            }
        }
        customRequestCodeGallery -> {
            data.let {
                when {
                    data?.clipData != null -> {
                        for (i in 0 until data.clipData!!.itemCount) {
                            val uri = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                            val file = File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/MyApp/${Utils.getNameFromUri(contentResolver, uri)?:""}")
                            file.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream!!)
                        }
                    }
                    data?.data != null -> {
                        val uri = data.data!!
                        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                        val file = File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/MyApp/${Utils.getNameFromUri(contentResolver, uri)?:""}")
                        file.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        customRequestCodeFile -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data.let {
                when {
                    data?.clipData != null -> {
                        for (i in 0 until data.clipData!!.itemCount) {
                            val uri = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                            val file = File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/MyApp/${Utils.getNameFromUri(contentResolver, uri)?:""}")
                            file.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream!!)
                        }
                    }
                    data?.data != null -> {
                        val uri = data.data!!
                        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                        val file = File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/MyApp/${Utils.getNameFromUri(contentResolver, uri)?:""}")
                        file.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you haven't mentioned the language I am assuming it is kotlin. Even if you are using Java you have to just pick up flags and actions from my pickers.

On early Android Versions there was no issue while accessing URI's but from Pie (or might be Oreo) it changed and now there are restrictions.

My Gallery Picker is just for picking Images. But File Picker is for the apps which dont expose their file providers and you dont get files from there. So some URI's you are storing are useless. Figure out through which app you pick images from work and which dont. If its necessary for you to pick files from these restricted apps then you have to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT flag. The exception you are getting is telling you to use this flag.

Comment: yeah, I solved it, thank kiu very much. And I think I should change the title of the discusstion!

Comment: Good to hear it.